# Efficent methods for finding most common phrases in a body of text AKA trending topics

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures, data-mining

I previously asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928997/how-to-find-common-phrases-in-a-large-body-of-text) on this topic, I ended up deriving several solutions which worked, one based on bloom filters + ngrams, the other based on hash tables + ngrams. Both solutions perform fine with small data sets (<1000 texts, usually tweets) but the computation time grew exponentially meaning doing 10,000 could take hours.

I am currently working in Ruby and perhaps, that is the problem but are there any other solutions or approaches I could attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you store n-grams in Ruby?

Comment: As an array of words? You might save lots of memory (perhaps gain some speed as well) by converting them to symbols beforehand.

Comment: I was assuming that you were tokenizing the words initially. And then the problem is essentially the same as a compression problem, which I wish I knew more about. But there are a fair number of compression algorithms around.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do text searching in large sets of data, you might have to look into something like solr.  There is a really easy to setup solr gem called sunspot http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by following the steps below:

- (Optional, for performance purpose) Run through all the documents, create a mapping between the a unique word and an integer. Also, it is better to create a special mapping for sentence termination (.!? etc.). This is to facilitate the check of phrases that do not cross sentence boundary.
- Concatenate all the documents into a huge array of mapped integers (in previous step). This can be done online (to save space) as we go through the next steps.
- Constructing a [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) of the string in previous step, augmented with the [longest common prefix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array). The fastest implementation known is SA-IS that runs in O(n) worst-case time. See [here](https://sites.google.com/site/yuta256/sais). Some special handling is required to be sure that each common prefix does not cross the sentence boundary.
- LCP array is basically the result you need. You can do whatever you want with it, such as: sort it to find the longest repeated phrases among the documents, find all 5-words, 4 words, 3-words phrases, etc. The most common phrases (I assume at least 2-word phrases here) can be found by looking at both the LCP and suffix array.

Quick Google search show that [this library](https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms) contains a Ruby suffix array implementation. You can generate LCP array from there in  O(n) [Reference](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs548/references/linear_lcp.pdf).