# Finding 2 & 3 word Phrases Using R TM Package

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining

I am trying to find a code that actually works to find the most frequently used two and three word phrases in R text mining package (maybe there is another package for it that I do not know). I have been trying to use the tokenizer, but seem to have no luck.

If you worked on a similar situation in the past, could you post a code that is tested and actually works? Thank you so much!

Comment: Ordered phrases, that is? Or co-occurences?

Comment: Both would be useful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You can pass in a custom tokenizing function to `tm`'s `DocumentTermMatrix` function, so if you have package `tau` installed it's fairly straightforward.

```
library(tm); library(tau);

tokenize_ngrams <- function(x, n=3) return(rownames(as.data.frame(unclass(textcnt(x,method="string",n=n)))))

texts <- c("This is the first document.", "This is the second file.", "This is the third text.")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts))
matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=tokenize_ngrams))
```

Where `n` in the `tokenize_ngrams` function is the number of words per phrase. This feature is also implemented in package `RTextTools`, which further simplifies things.

```
library(RTextTools)
texts <- c("This is the first document.", "This is the second file.", "This is the third text.")
matrix <- create_matrix(texts,ngramLength=3)
```

This returns a class of `DocumentTermMatrix` for use with package `tm`.

Comment: I realize this is a pretty stale thread, but has anybody tried this recently? In my hands, the first method gives the following error: `> matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=tokenize_ngrams))
Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  : 
  'i, j, v' different lengths
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion`.

Comment: I get the same error, @MAndrecPhD, when trying the `library(RTextTools)` example.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have seen some people suggest that SnowballC package will solve it, but it does not for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I add the following the simple_triplet_matrix error no longer appears 
options(mc.cores=1)

however I get the following error instead
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-character argument

Answer (score 8):

This is part 5 of the [FAQ](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams) of the [tm](/questions/tagged/tm) package:

> *5. Can I use bigrams instead of single tokens in a term-document matrix?*
>
> Yes. RWeka provides a tokenizer for arbitrary n-grams which can be
> directly passed on to the term-document matrix constructor. E.g.:

```
  library("RWeka")
  library("tm")

  data("crude")

  BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))

  inspect(tdm[340:345,1:10])
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Actually, the current version of the FAQ has a solution that doesn't require RWeka: http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams

Comment: if you can figure out how to get rJava working so that you can use the RWeka package. Would be nice to see a non-Java-dependent solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is my own made up creation for different purposes but I think may applicable to your needs too:

```
#User Defined Functions
Trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

breaker <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?*-])", perl=TRUE))

strip <- function(x, digit.remove = TRUE, apostrophe.remove = FALSE){
    strp <- function(x, digit.remove, apostrophe.remove){
        x2 <- Trim(tolower(gsub(".*?($|'|[^[:punct:]]).*?", "\\1", as.character(x))))
        x2 <- if(apostrophe.remove) gsub("'", "", x2) else x2
        ifelse(digit.remove==TRUE, gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", x2), x2)
    }
unlist(lapply(x, function(x) Trim(strp(x =x, digit.remove = digit.remove, 
    apostrophe.remove = apostrophe.remove)) ))
}

unblanker <- function(x)subset(x, nchar(x)>0)

#Fake Text Data
x <- "I like green eggs and ham.  They are delicious.  They taste so yummy.  I'm talking about ham and eggs of course"

#The code using Base R to Do what you want
breaker(x)
strip(x)
words <- unblanker(breaker(strip(x)))
textDF <- as.data.frame(table(words))
textDF$characters <- sapply(as.character(textDF$words), nchar)
textDF2 <- textDF[order(-textDF$characters, textDF$Freq), ]
rownames(textDF2) <- 1:nrow(textDF2)
textDF2
subset(textDF2, characters%in%2:3)
```

Comment: Hi, @Tyler-Rinker, I know this is a few years old now, but i get this error when testing your code: ` Error in FUN(c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",  : 
  could not find function "Trim" `

Comment: Added `Trim` if that helps.

Comment: haha. Thanks, @Tyler_Rinker. I had a function of the exact same called `trim` but I didn't realize that was what it was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The **corpus** library has a function called `term_stats` that does what you want:

```
library(corpus)
corpus <- gutenberg_corpus(55) # Project Gutenberg #55, _The Wizard of Oz_
text_filter(corpus)$drop_punct <- TRUE # ignore punctuation
term_stats(corpus, ngrams = 2:3)
##    term             count support
## 1  of the             336       1
## 2  the scarecrow      208       1
## 3  to the             185       1
## 4  and the            166       1
## 5  said the           152       1
## 6  in the             147       1
## 7  the lion           141       1
## 8  the tin            123       1
## 9  the tin woodman    114       1
## 10 tin woodman        114       1
## 11 i am                84       1
## 12 it was              69       1
## 13 in a                64       1
## 14 the great           63       1
## 15 the wicked          61       1
## 16 wicked witch        60       1
## 17 at the              59       1
## 18 the little          59       1
## 19 the wicked witch    58       1
## 20 back to             57       1
## ⋮  (52511 rows total)
```

Here, `count` is the number of appearances, and `support` is the number of documents containing the term.

Answer (score 1):

I add a similar problem by using `tm` and `ngram` packages.
After debugging `mclapply`, I saw there where problems on documents with less than 2 words with the following error

```
   input 'x' has nwords=1 and n=2; must have nwords >= n
```

So I've added a filter to remove document with low word count number:

```
    myCorpus.3 <- tm_filter(myCorpus.2, function (x) {
      length(unlist(strsplit(stringr::str_trim(x$content), '[[:blank:]]+'))) > 1
    })
```

Then my tokenize function looks like:

```
bigramTokenizer <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)

  # Find words
  one.list <- c()
  tryCatch({
    one.gram <- ngram::ngram(x, n = 1)
    one.list <- ngram::get.ngrams(one.gram)
  }, 
  error = function(cond) { warning(cond) })

  # Find 2-grams
  two.list <- c()
  tryCatch({
    two.gram <- ngram::ngram(x, n = 2)
    two.list <- ngram::get.ngrams(two.gram)
  },
  error = function(cond) { warning(cond) })

  res <- unlist(c(one.list, two.list))
  res[res != '']
}
```

Then you can test the function with:

```
dtmTest <- lapply(myCorpus.3, bigramTokenizer)
```

And finally:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus.3, control = list(tokenize = bigramTokenizer))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try tidytext package

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidyr
```

)

Suppose I have a dataframe CommentData that contains comment column and I want to find occurrence of two words together. Then try

```
bigram_filtered <- CommentData %>%
  unnest_tokens(bigram, Comment, token= "ngrams", n=2) %>%
  separate(bigram, c("word1","word2"), sep=" ") %>%
  filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word,
         !word2 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
  count(word1, word2, sort=TRUE)
```

The above code creates tokens, and then remove stop words that doesn't help in analysis(eg. the,an,to etc.) Then you count occurrence of these words. You will be then using unite function to combine individual words and record their occurrence.

```
bigrams_united <- bigram_filtered %>%
  unite(bigram, word1, word2, sep=" ")
bigrams_united
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(class)
library(wordcloud)

keywords <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, na.strings=c("NA","-","?"))
keywords_doc <- Corpus(VectorSource(keywords$"use your column that you need"))
keywords_doc <- tm_map(keywords_doc, removeNumbers)
keywords_doc <- tm_map(keywords_doc, tolower)
keywords_doc <- tm_map(keywords_doc, stripWhitespace)
keywords_doc <- tm_map(keywords_doc, removePunctuation)
keywords_doc <- tm_map(keywords_doc, PlainTextDocument)
keywords_doc <- tm_map(keywords_doc, stemDocument)
```

This is the bigrams or tri grams section that you could use

```
BigramTokenizer <-  function(x)
unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 2), paste, collapse = " "), use.names = FALSE)
# creating of document matrix
keywords_matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(keywords_doc, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))

# remove sparse terms 
keywords_naremoval <- removeSparseTerms(keywords_matrix, 0.95)

# Frequency of the words appearing
keyword.freq <- rowSums(as.matrix(keywords_naremoval))
subsetkeyword.freq <-subset(keyword.freq, keyword.freq >=20)
frequentKeywordSubsetDF <- data.frame(term = names(subsetkeyword.freq), freq = subsetkeyword.freq) 

# Sorting of the words
frequentKeywordDF <- data.frame(term = names(keyword.freq), freq = keyword.freq)
frequentKeywordSubsetDF <- frequentKeywordSubsetDF[with(frequentKeywordSubsetDF, order(-frequentKeywordSubsetDF$freq)), ]
frequentKeywordDF <- frequentKeywordDF[with(frequentKeywordDF, order(-frequentKeywordDF$freq)), ]

# Printing of the words
wordcloud(frequentKeywordDF$term, freq=frequentKeywordDF$freq, random.order = FALSE, rot.per=0.35, scale=c(5,0.5), min.freq = 30, colors = brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
```

Hope this helps. This is an entire code that you could use.

Comment: I have tried all of the solutions but none was working with my data. And I don't know why. The result is alway 1gram (i.e. one word) no matter what value I leave in the ngams function (2, 3, 4, etc.)