# RTextTools create_matrix returns non-character argument error

Tags: r, text-mining

I am new to text processing with R. I'm trying the simple code below

`library(RTextTools)
texts <- c("This is the first document.", "This is the second file.", "This is the third text.")
matrix <- create_matrix(texts,ngramLength=3)`

which is one of the answers in the question [Finding 2 & 3 word Phrases Using R TM Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898521/finding-2-3-word-phrases-using-r-tm-package)

However, it gives an error `Error in FUN(X[[2L]], ...) : non-character argument` instead.

I can generate a document term matrix when I drop the `ngramLength` parameter, but I do need to search for phrases of certain word length. Any suggestions of alternative or corrections?

Comment: I have this problem as well. I've run a number of text cleaning packages/functions on the text to clean it and it IS character and it looks fine when I inspect it visually.

Comment: One solution I found online suggested the use of `texts <- textcnt(as.character(df)` before create_matrix but I get the same error. I am going to try to contact the author of this package.

Answer (score 3):

ngramLength seems not to work. Here is a workaround:

```
library(RTextTools)
library(tm)
library(RWeka) # this library is needed for NGramTokenizer
library 
texts <- c("This is the first document.", 
           "Is this a text?", 
           "This is the second file.", 
           "This is the third text.", 
           "File is not this.") 
TrigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(texts)),
                         control=list(
                                      weighting = weightTf,
                                      tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))

as.matrix(dtm)
```

The tokenizer uses `RWeka`'s `NGramTokenizer` instead of the tokenizer called by `create_matrix`. You can now use `dtm` in the other RTextTools functions, like training a classification model below:

```
isText <- c(T,F,T,T,F)
container <- create_container(dtm, isText, virgin=F, trainSize=1:3, testSize=4:5)

models=train_models(container, algorithm=c("SVM","BOOSTING"))
classify_models(container, models)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same error. I found a fix in this pull request https://github.com/timjurka/RTextTools/pull/5/files. I did the change by "trace(create_matrix,edit=T)". Now it works :)

Comment: This seems like the correct solution. However that fix doesn't seem to be incorporated into the latest RTextTools in CRAN. How did you implement it?

Comment: For now, I am managing it with trace i.e. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/trace.html. I am planning to contact the developer or build the package from the source

Comment: I don't understand, I thought `trace` is only to debug, do you mean `trace` can be used to replace the part of the code that requires fixing?

Comment: Yes, trace is for debug. But it can be used as a temporary workaround to get rid of this issue. Only downside is that the fix which we add using trace gets lost whenever R session is restarted. So fix has to be applied whenever R/RStudio is restarted,So it a ugly workaround, but it works

Comment: I downloaded the source and updated this change. Then I installed the package from this updated source. Now it works permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an issue with Character (input data type). Same error when I use the NYTimes dataset , which is provided withe the package and run the same code as accompanied in the help manual.