# Text Mining in R: Counting 2-3 word phrases

Tags: r, text-mining

I found a very useful piece of code within Stackoverflow - [Finding 2 & 3 word Phrases Using R TM Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898521/finding-2-3-word-phrases-using-r-tm-package)
(credit @patrick perry) to show the frequency of 2 and 3 word phrases within a corpus:

```
library(corpus)
corpus <- gutenberg_corpus(55) # Project Gutenberg #55, _The Wizard of Oz_
text_filter(corpus)$drop_punct <- TRUE # ignore punctuation
term_stats(corpus, ngrams = 2:3)
##    term             count support
## 1  of the             336       1
## 2  the scarecrow      208       1
## 3  to the             185       1
## 4  and the            166       1
## 5  said the           152       1
## 6  in the             147       1
## 7  the lion           141       1
## 8  the tin            123       1
## 9  the tin woodman    114       1
## 10 tin woodman        114       1
## 11 i am                84       1
## 12 it was              69       1
## 13 in a                64       1
## 14 the great           63       1
## 15 the wicked          61       1
## 16 wicked witch        60       1
## 17 at the              59       1
## 18 the little          59       1
## 19 the wicked witch    58       1
## 20 back to             57       1
## ⋮  (52511 rows total)
```

How do you ensure that frequency counts of phrases like "the tin" are not also included in the frequency count of "the tin woodman" or the "tin woodman"?

Thanks

Comment: Remove stopwords.

Comment: Read the help with `text_filter`. In there you can drop lots of stuff. 'text_filter(corpus, drop = stopwords_en)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing stopwords can remove noise from the data, causing issues such as those you are having a above:

```
library(tm)
library(corpus)
library(dplyr)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(gutenberg_corpus(55)))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
term_stats(corpus, ngrams = 2:3) %>% 
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  group_by(grp = str_extract(as.character(term), "\\w+\\s+\\w+")) %>% 
  mutate(count_unique = ifelse(length(unique(count)) > 1, max(count) - min(count), count)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

Comment: Thanks @hello_friend. If the issue occurs in phrases without stop word such as "northern ireland" and "northern ireland counties". Is there a way to avoid double counting?

Comment: @Mcguns please see revised solution above

Comment: ran on my own data and works great, thanks very much the tibble output is what I need.
I can't provide the original data in full but I've tried this code again but changing to ngrams = 1:3 to examine single words too but it's difficult to determine the output

Comment: The regex in the str_extract in the original function won't stand up to 1:3, it works for 2:3.

Comment: Thanks @hello_friend - I'll keep the single word and 2-3 phrases analysis separate and work out counts by comparison to make sure no double counting for frequency analysis