# Discovering "templates" in a given text?

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp, machine-learning, data-mining, nltk

If I have significant amounts of text and am trying to discover templates that occur most frequently, I was thinking of solving it using the N-Gram approach and in fact it was suggested as a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426383/what-techniques-tools-are-there-for-discovering-common-phrases-in-chunks-of-text) question as well but my requirement is slightly different. Just to clarify, I have some text like this:

```
I wake up every day morning and read the newspaper and then go to work
I wake up every day morning and eat my breakfast and then go to work
I am not sure that this is the solution but I will try
I am not sure that this is the answer but I will try
I am not feeling well today but I will get the work done and deliver it tomorrow
I was not feeling well yesterday but I will get the work done and let you know by tomorrow
```

and am trying to extract "templates" like this:

```
I wake up every day morning and ... and then go to work
I am not sure that this is the ... but I will try
I ... not feeling well ... but I will get the work done and ... tomorrow
```

I am looking for an approach that can scale to million of lines of text so I was just wondering if I can adapt the same N-gram approach to solve this problem or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Millions of lines of text isn't a really big number :)

What you're looking for is at least similar to collocation finding. You could try to compute pointwise mutual information on n-grams. See [Manning & Schütze (1999)](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/colloc/) for this and other approaches to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I finally got the book today :)